# How to skip target from getting updated in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In my project, I have the following requirements for my makefile

1. We have a makefile which includes common makefile that defines many macros and many rules *.c and *.o if they do not exist.
2. In my makefile, dependencies should be checked for existence for a given target
3. If there is an update in dependencies (time stamp), the target should be updated.
4. But at any case (though dependency does not exist), no special rule (defined in step 1) should be executed for my dependencies from common makefile. I would like to skip the rules defined in common makefile. Simply check for dependency, time stamp and never ever execute any rule for dependencies specified.
5. Order-only prerequisite is not helping here because if there is an update in dependencies, the target is not updated.

Example

```
all: bin
bin: a.o
a.o: a.c ---->(check existance and timestamp, but never to go to target a.c at any case. Error is ok if file is not present)
    echo building a.o
    touch a.o
a.c:   ---> (Assume that this rule is included from common makefile)
    touch a.c
    enter code here
```

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this, if you don't rely to heavily on the common macros. How do you use them?

Comment: common macros is defined in top level makefile like this %.c:

Comment: But anyway how I have replaced makefile code with shell script inside target using find with newer option.